# Bind contact with another application

Tags: android

I'm trying to bind contact between my device and other application by outer id. How can I do it?

```
ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ops = new ArrayList < ContentProviderOperation > ();
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(
        ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds...?)
        .build());
```